# How to show devise error messages one by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, error-handling, devise

I'm writing an app and I'm using devise for signup and login purposes.

I'm now validating registration form fields and I can check and show the "non-validated" data by using the "<%= devise_error_messages! %>".

The thing is that I don't want to show all the errors in the same div, I'd like to put error 1 in one div, error 2 in another div and so on.

For example: If an user insert an already taken username and leave the email field empty, I'd like to show:

1. "Username already taken" close to the username field
2. "Email can't be blank" close to the email field

Thank you

Comment: [`devise_error_messages!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views) is just a helper method. You can just override it or show the error messages one by one next to the fields yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I show messages one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can always iterate over the errors in the resource.

So if you for looks similar to this:

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(...`

You can simple, get the errors inside the resource and show them, like so:

```
<% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <div><%= msg %></div>
<% end %>
```

`errors.full_messages` - will give you an array with nice errors messages that you can display to the user.

Comment: Thank you, I did this but the result is the same. I'm having all the error messages in the same place. I wish to have username error shown below the username field, password error shown below the password field and so on..

Comment: `errors` object is a hash, you can easily pick and choose the errors you want to display based on the field's name:

<%= f.text_field :user_name %>
<%= resource.errors[:user_name] %>

Answer (score 0):

I solved it creating an initializer with this

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|   unless html_tag 
=~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" 
class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe   end end
```

This gave me the exact result that I was looking for.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrbR.png)

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Raffaelle you mean you created a file and added it to the intializer folder? How then did you get the errors to display in the view?